# Python dict: How to map keys to values, where key is a range?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, range

I have a list of values:

[0,1.51, 2.01, 2.51, 3.01,5.01, 6.01,7.01, 8.01,9.01, 10.01]

And a second list of values:

[.15, .22, .3, .37, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]

The rough logic of my programme is that if the value of some variable falls between two values in the first list, then set the value of another variable to the corresponding item in the second list i.e.

```
if 0 < x < 1.51:
    y = 0.15
elif 1.51 < x < 2.01:
    y = .22
and so on
```

Obviousy I could extend the if/elif/else flow to cover each case, but (i) this is not pretty, (ii) it's not sustainable (iii) I want to be able to apply this to any two lists, not neededing to know any of the values contained within.

What's are the best ways of achieving this in Python?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    m=[0,1.51, 2.01, 2.51, 3.01,5.01, 6.01,7.01, 8.01,9.01, 10.01]
    n=[.15, .22, .3, .37, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, 1]



    def test(x,a,b):
       for i in range(len(a)-1):
             if a[i] < x <a[i+1]:return b[i]

    >>>>test(3,m,n)
    >>>> 0.37
    >>>>test(.32,n,m)
    >>>> 2.01
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the bisect module - http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

And the example there for percentage->grades:

```
>>> def grade(score, breakpoints=[60, 70, 80, 90], grades='FDCBA'):
        i = bisect(breakpoints, score)
        return grades[i]

>>> [grade(score) for score in [33, 99, 77, 70, 89, 90, 100]]
['F', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: Needs a slight tweak - but changing to check `> 0` before starting and  removing `0` from the bounds it should work nicely.